# Identity 2.0 ApplicationRoleManager and ApplicationUserManager returing null from OWIN Context

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, owin

The project is Web API 2.0. I have a controller where I am trying to add roles to the Identity tables. I am using OWIN middleware. In addition, I am using StructureMap for DI. Both the ApplicationUserManager and ApplicationRoleManager are returning null values in the controller.

My Startup class

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
        ConfigureOAuth(app);
        WebApiConfig.Register(config);
        app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        app.UseWebApi(config);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApartmentContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationRoleManager>(ApplicationRoleManager.Create);

        config.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerActivator), new ServiceActivator(config));
        ConfigureContainer();            
    }
```

DI Container

```
 public void ConfigureContainer()
    {
        ObjectFactory.Configure(x =>
            {
                x.For<DbContext>().Use(() => new ApartmentContext());
                x.For<IAuthRepository>().Use<AuthRepository>();
                x.For<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>>().Use<UserStore<ApplicationUser>>();
                x.For<IRoleStore<ApplicationRole,string>>().Use<RoleStore<ApplicationRole>>();
            });
    }
```

Code Inside Controller <--- All methods return NULL. The OWIN context IS retrieved but not the value of the GET<>.

```
            var test1 = Request.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
            var test2 = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
            var test3 = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationUserManager>();
            var test4 = Request.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationRoleManager>();
            var test5 = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationRoleManager>();
```

These USING statements are in the controller(Amongst others):

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;

// Configure the RoleManager used in the application. RoleManager is defined in the ASP.NET Identity core assembly
public class ApplicationRoleManager : RoleManager<ApplicationRole>
{
    public ApplicationRoleManager(IRoleStore<ApplicationRole, string> roleStore)
        : base(roleStore)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationRoleManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationRoleManager> options, IOwinContext context)
    {
        return new ApplicationRoleManager(new RoleStore<ApplicationRole>(context.Get<ApartmentContext>()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only reason Owin needs to know about how to create `ApplicationUserManager` is to be able to invalidate cookie if security stamp have been changed on a user. (You configure this in Auth.Startup.cs, giving how often to check for cookie to be valid)

So you can go configure your container all the way and inject your `ApplicationUserManager` and `ApplicationRoleManager` in a constructor in your controllers. And don't use `GetUserManager` on Owin context - this is a hidden anti-pattern of service locator. This is an Identity's attempt to replace DI-container without forcing anyone to use a specific container.

As for the nulls you get, does `ApplicationUserManager.Create` return an actual object or a null?

Comment: Thanks for the reply - To answer your question, a null is returned, no object is instantiated. Your suggestion sounds logical and worth a try , however, I would still be curious as to why the nulls are being returned.

Comment: If your `ApplicationUserManager.Create` returns null, show the code - problem is there.

Comment: Added ApplicationRoleManager.Create